# Call derived class method

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

I have a base class:

```
class motorcycle
{
public:

   virtual int speed()
   { return 0; }
}
```

And some classes that inherits the base class (only 2 in the example, but i can have a lot of classes):

```
class honda: public motorcycle 
{
public:

   int speed()
   { return 2; }
}

class yamaha: public motorcycle 
{
public:

   int speed()
   { return 1; }
}
```

I have a pointer to the base class that points to one of the derived class:

```
honda* h = new honda();
...
int speed = get_speed(h);
```

Where `get_speed` is:

```
int get_speed(motorcycle* m)
{
    // How to return speed according to m class?
}
```

Now, what is the best method to return speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int get_speed(motorcycle* m)
{
    return m->speed();
}
```

Comment: `speed` is not a pure virtual method.

Comment: @Nick it is virtual, that's enough. It doesn't have to be pure for polymorphism to work. Why would you think so?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore because i was wrong, thanks. But if it was not virtual?

Comment: @Nick then your design is broken. You could call it after casting or some other ugly work-arounds.